# Помогите с анимацией scale

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите сделать анимацию чтобы при клике по кнопке див с замедлением появлялся с трансформацией [scale]  с еулевого размера увеличивался до своего нормального состояния

Comment: А в чём проблема-то?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').addClass('anim-scale');
})
```

```css
div {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  transition: 2s linear;
}
div.anim-scale {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ведь и вправду — красивые вещи делаются просто!

Answer (score 9):

Есть ещё вариант одним скриптом. Но вариант *soledar10* более практичный, как по мне

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $({scale: 0}).animate({scale: 1}, {
    duration: 1000, // скорость
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function(scale) {
      $('div').css('transform', 'scale('+scale+')')
    }
  });
})
```

```css
div {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: tomato;
  transition: 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Нажми</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам всем